# Marionette.js: Should regions replace instead of insert?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

The default behavior of marionette.js is to append a template into the element specified by the regions selector.  However, I usually end up having to create a special region type and override the appendHtml function to do a replace instead.

That is not too difficult, but why is append the default?

I usually will create the layout template with an empty div to specify where the region should go.  Then I replace that div with sub template when I show it.

I guess am wondering if there I'm missing the design pattern for templates that makes append more intuitive.

Thanks for the help.

Update:

So I usually will have some view for something I want rendered into the page and will want to todd n element onto the page where I want it.  I will do javascript that will look something like this:

```
ReplaceRegion = Marionette.Region.extend({
    open: function(view){
        this.$el.replaceWith(view.el);
    }
});

App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
App.addRegions({
  myRegion: {
    selector: "#someRegion",
    regionType: ReplaceRegion
  }
};

var view = new CoolWidgetView(); 

App.myRegion.show(view);
```

And then somewhere in my html I'll throw an empty div in the mix where I want my template to show up.

```
<div id="mywidget"></div>
```

Now if it is the only child element, I can use a selector that would just be the parent, but that becomes more tricky when the view i'm inserting has siblings.

Also, I'm not really asking for a change to the default, as much as I'm wondering if there's a better way to insert items where you would like them in your layouts.  I'm still relatively new to the layout and design of these things so anything helps!

Thanks Derick for writing great software!

Comment: Can you expand on the scenario that you need, where "replace" is necessary and the default behavior doesn't work? Also, can you post the code that you end up writing, as well? Lastly - this might be a better question / discussion on the Github issues: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues

Comment: Hey @DerickBailey, would you suggest also ask this up on the github page?

Comment: While I'm familiar with Backbone, I'm a Marionette neophyte, so regard this comment appropriately.  I've used replace when the region will contain an ItemView with a span tagName, i.e., where I can't have a containing (region id name) div for the ItemView, or it'll break the HTML layout.

Comment: I didn't totally understand MattyP's scenario but one example is a sidebar with 3 sections of links.  You may have 3 regions, each containing a CollectionView.  If the regions replaced their el with the view's el then you could style them like this: `.sidebar ul { margin-bottom: 10px } .sidebar ul:last-child { margin-bottom: 0 }`.  With the default behavior all of the ul's will be last-child.

Answer (score 0):

Marionette regions provide both a `show` and a `close` method. Have you tried closing the region before you show the new one?

[Marionette.Region docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#basic-use)

Comment: So I asked this a long while back.  I don't think it is a useful question.  In spending more time with backbone and marionette i've found it to not be much of an issue.